# how to load text data first then images while making api call reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using `react` and `redux` for my application. I have to build one functionality where all text data will be loaded first and then images. I would like to know how to load text data first then images while fetching data from endpoints. Till images are not there I want to show gif images.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am actually not getting how to do it, can u help me. what procedure should i follow. currently I am showing all data based on the api call. Thanks for your response.

Comment: therefore my application is becoming slow, I want to improve performance so I am thinking to load text data first and then images.

Comment: this.props.usedvehiclelist.data.data.map((oldcardata)=>{
        result = __.filter(this.props.usedvehicleimages.data.data, function(o) {
        return o.pre_owned_car_list_id.id==oldcardata.id;
    });
    mediaarr = __.sampleSize(result, 3);
}

Comment: This is how I am mapping through all the data. mediaarr is containing images.

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback of the api call to get the text, get the images.

Comment: Hi I am not getting can you explain little more

Comment: If it is the same end point, an event will only be triggered when the entire thing has been received. Either find a way to make it two endpoints or, to improve performance, you can manually put place holder text that is replaced with the images when the data has been rendered.

Comment: thanks for your response. I used react-lazyload to load images.